# Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1

Tags: vue.js, netlify

I am trying to deploy my vue app on netlify but getting this error and here is the log
Tried reading other answers on Stackoverflow but still nothing works.

Here is the log
`https://pastebin.com/gt0xMhaG`

Here package.json

```
{
  "name": "invoice",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.4"
  },
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "firebase": "^9.0.1",
    "uid": "^2.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.0.11",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have package-lock.json file commited to your code repository. If so, delete it from the repo, and then trigger the deploy again. Netlify build file when it finds package-lock.json

Answer (score 0):

From your logs, it seems your runtime environment is using node v16.13.0. The error is regarding node-sass, which had problems with node v16^. So your error is triggered during build time. Read this thread

https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/3103

You may need to use something like node 14 in your runtime environment or move to some other sass package like dart-sass

```
11:09:31 PM: Build ready to start
11:09:33 PM: build-image version: 8925038cf853b22d6397cdcb9904ac88b66bb383 (focal)
11:09:33 PM: build-image tag: v4.5.0
11:09:33 PM: buildbot version: 26b97d2791a6a6b761b2a82710f290ed779fac72
11:09:33 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
11:09:33 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
11:09:33 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
11:09:33 PM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
11:09:33 PM: git clone https://github.com/utkzas/digital-bill-book
11:09:34 PM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/main
11:09:35 PM: Parsing package.json dependencies
11:09:35 PM: Starting build script
11:09:35 PM: Installing dependencies
11:09:35 PM: Python version set to 2.7
11:09:36 PM: v16.13.0 is already installed.
11:09:36 PM: Now using node v16.13.0 (npm v8.1.0) <----- see this
```